# Div behave incorrectly when “<select>” is used; works fine when “<input>” is used

Tags: html, css

I have code as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/PJcZQ/. It has tow divs with similar content “GROUP1” and “GROUP2” – only difference being the following

GROUP 1

```
  <div class="secondTextBox">
  <select name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$ddlStatus" id="detailContentPlaceholder_ddlStatus" class="dropdownItem" style="width: 120px;">
  </select>
  </div>
```

GROUP 2

```
 <div class="secondTextBox">
 <input name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$txtVal2" type="text" id="detailContentPlaceholder_txtVal2" style="width: 120px;" />
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.searchValuesDiv
{
padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
margin:20px 0 20px 0px;
border:1px solid Cyan;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Group 1 is not behaving as expected – the div containing the button starts from a wrong position.

**Note**: This issue is not reproducible while seeing from jsFiddle. This can be reproduced when a HTML page is created with that code.

1. Why is it behaving so? [Can you explain why it was not a problem when I used "Input" element?]
2. How can we correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing float in the `.searchLine`.. I hope it fix your problem

Change the css to this:

```
.searchLine
{    
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    min-width:700px;
    height:auto;
    margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

or

```
.searchLine
{    
    clear:both;
    width:auto;
    min-width:700px;
    height:auto;
    margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why it was not a problem when I used "Input" element?

Comment: Its because the elements inside the div `.searchLine` have a float. Other way to solve it is adding a `clear: both` in the `.searchLine`

Comment: I am using the same .searchLine even when I use "Input" element. Still why it works with "Input" element?

Comment: It just behave like this in some browsers. For example, it works fine in Chrome. It depends on how browser handle with css.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using floats. If you want the `.btnSearchDiv` element to start in a “new line”, just add a `overflow: hidden;` to the `.searchLine` elements. Without that, those elements are collapsed because they contain floating elements.

Comment: Can you explain why it was not a problem when I used "Input" element?

Comment: It is not that it “works” with the input element. Seems like a condition happening in your environment, because I see no difference in the two examples. I just guessed what you were trying to achieve, the HTML itself was clear enough for that.
In your case I think that the select element is drawn with a height slightly smaller than the input element, that is why the float element will stop its float with the next taller element to the left. That is why a `clear: left;` (as I suggested first) fixes the issue. But I prefer the `overflow: hidden;` method. Since it will fix the containing div.

Comment: @Lijo here is an example that better explains my... explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/HfF27/4/ (Change the width of the rendered example so you see what happens)

Comment: +1 for best answer... thanks for the fiddle - now i understand clearly those float issues